# Can the keyword using be used in partial specialisation?

Tags: c++11, templates

Given:

```
template <class T, class P>
struct A;

template <class P> 
struct B {};
```

I can write:

```
template <class P>
struct A<int,P> : B<P> {};
```

But that is tedious as I have to redefine constructors. Is there a way to write something similar to:

```
template <class P>
using A<int,P> = B<P>;
```

Comment: You know you can inherit constructors now, do you? `struct A<int,P> : B<P> { using B::B; };`

Comment: Yes, I do. Still you have to state so. Not such a big fan of constructor inheritance.

Comment: You have to state *something* one way or another. (I have to correct myself, `using B<P>::B;` is the right formula)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do:

```
template <class T, class P> struct A_impl;

template <class P> struct A_impl<int,P>
{
    using type = B<P>;
};

template <class T, class P> using A = typename A_impl<T,P>::type;

// Now `A<int,P>` is an alias for `B<P>`.
```

The code uses [*type alias template*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) from C++11.

---

As an alternative, you could import all constructors from `B<P>` into `A<int,P>` with a single `using`.

It looks less optimal to me, but still could be used.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T, class P> struct A;

template <class P> struct B
{
    B(int) {std::cout << "B(int)\n";}
};

template <class P> struct A<int,P> : B<P>
{
    using B<P>::B; // <--
};

int main()
{
    A<int, void> a(42); // Prints `B(int)`.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How would the first solution work with respect to other partial specializations of A (e,g, on T), or even a general unspecialized instance of A?

Comment: @Fabio It would work without any problems for those cases too.